# How to output all the indices of a value from an input file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to find all the indices of a value in an input file. The program will accept the number to be searched for as 1st command line argument, and the name of the input file as the second argument. I'm having trouble to output the indices at which the value was found from the code below:

```
import sys

value = sys.argv[1]
file_name = sys.argv[2]
file = open(file_name, 'r')

print('The value of file \"{}\" to be searched:\n{}'.format(file_name, value))

for line in file.readlines():
    curr_arr = []
    for i in line.split(','):
        curr_arr +=[int(i)]

def find_values(curr_arr, val):
    found_indexes = []
    sum = 0
    for n in range(len(curr_arr)):
        sum += curr_arr[n]
        if curr_arr[n] == val:
            found_indexes += [n]
        sum = sum + 1
    return found_indexes

print 'The index(s) of the occurrence of {} in {}: {}'.format(value, curr_arr, find_values(curr_arr, value))
```

And this is what I get:

```
a1.py 7 text.csv
The value of file "text.csv" to be searched:
7
The index(s) of the occurrence of 7 in [2, 3, 7, 9, 7, 3, 2]:
```

I'm supposed to get [2, 4] but it returns none. Could anyone help me with the code? Thank you

Comment: Notice how you reset the `curr_arr` for each line you read (`curr_arr = []`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `value` is currently a string. You should cast to int so the comparison with items in the array which are ints can be `True` for matching items:

```
value = int(sys.argv[1])
```

Otherwise, `if curr_arr[n] == val: ...` is always `False`, and the `found_indices` list remains empty.

Besides, you can build the list much more elegantly using `enumerate` to generate indices alongside the items in a *list comprehension*.

```
found_indices = [i for i, x in curr_arr if x == value]
```